# Add a route to handle multiple HTTP requests in Slim PHP

Tags: php, slim

I am using the following code for "Routing using methods inside classes:"

```
$app->any('/contacts', 'Contacts:home');
```

My class looks like:

```
class Contacts {
    public function home() {
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

The above code works fine for me and when I open "http://localhost:3000/contacts"

**The Problem is when I try to handle multuple HTTP request**

```
$app->group('/users/{id:[0-9]+}', function() {
    $this->map(['GET', 'POST'], '', 'Users');
});
```

Is there anyway, I can pass class name such as **Users** in the above pseudo code and the code works for me, The class would be something like:

```
class Users {
    function get() {
        return 'asd';
    }
    function post() {
        return 'post';
    }
}
```

In such a way, that my request listens to the appropriate method.

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/get/) show it as `/users/:id`, not `/users/{id:whatever}`. I've not used Slim, but does the `:id` syntax work? Why are you adding a regular expression?

Comment: The regular expression works fine in SlimPHP, I've used the regular expression to tell that :id can only take numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a method that sorts out the current route's details than calls the correct method.

You can determine which method was used by calling the `$request->getOriginalMethod();` function, then using `call_user_func_array();` function you can call whichever of your functions is appropriate for the current method.